# bcrypt on php 5.2 or 5.3

Tags: php, hash, bcrypt

I want to use bcrypt hashing in PHP and shared servers I would use are ordinary Unix and I cannot install anything on them. The version of my php would be 5.3 or 5.2 and not 5.5 and this code using password_hash will not work.

```
$password = '123456';
$options = array(
    'cost' => 7,
    'salt' => 'BCryptRequires22Chrcts',
);
$hash=password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
```

even though there are a lot of conversations about bcrypt, I didn't find any clear command or code example about it.
php.net has a [page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) about crypt command which is so confuting for a beginner.
all I want is to implement such a function:

```
bcrypt($password,$salt)
```

is there any simple command(not dozens of codes including loops) to do that?
if not, is there any vulnerability purified code to download?

thanks in advance

Comment: Firstly, please stop using PHP 5.2 -- it was declared end-of-life more than two years ago, and has several unpatched security flaws.

Comment: @Spudley as said he uses a shared hosting. Often you can't update them your self

Comment: @Hendriq - then you should be using a different hosting company; any hosting company still forcing their users to stick with 5.2 is being negligent. It means they haven't done any security patching in two years on their PHP version, and they're probably also out of date patching other software on the server.

Comment: @Spudley, I can't argue with that.

Comment: i should add that i just used their trial service. maybe their premium is uses different version. on another server of one of my friends phpversion was 5.3.21

Comment: Well, my answer includes an alternative library that does work with 5.2, so if that's what you're stuck with then use that instead.

Comment: You have officially earned the "Totally Unprofessional PHP Developer" badge for using an extremely outdated PHP version. 5.2 is so old, it's a crime to use it. It's outdated since 2009.

Comment: @Panique, what do you mean by earn? earning money or using? and why do say using php 5.2 is a crime? according to which law?

Comment: The fixed salt is a problem. Also see Openwall's [PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its portable and hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords. The guy who wrote the framework (SolarDesigner) is the same guy who wrote [John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) and sits as a judge in the [Password Hashing Competition](http://password-hashing.net/). So he knows a thing or two about attacks on passwords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a library available to allow PHP 5.3 and 5.4 to use the new 5.5 `password_xxx()` functions.

You can download it [from here on Github](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

This library is written by the same PHP core developer who wrote the actual built-in `password_xxx()` functions in PHP 5.5, so it is 100% compatible. Just include it in your code and PHP 5.3 and 5.4 will be able to use these functions just as PHP 5.5 can.

The library is **not** compatible with PHP 5.2, because 5.2 is no longer supported (and has not been supported for over two years now). If you're using 5.2 you should be urgently considering upgrading.

Please also note that even on PHP 5.3, you need to be using a version greater than 5.3.7, as it relies on a feature that was fixed in that patch release. (the library will test for this when you run it).

If you absolutely *can't* upgrade your PHP to a version that is compatible with this library, then the next best option is to use an older password manager library written by the same author, called [PasswordLib](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHP-PasswordLib).

Comment: thanks but i cannot find anything about bcrypt there: https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHP-PasswordLib/blob/master/lib/PasswordLib/Hash/Hash.php

Comment: [The documentation states](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHP-PasswordLib#specifications) that it supports BCrypt (aka blowfish) and that it is the default hash type, and having used it I can vouch for the fact that it does generate bcrypt hashes. If you're reading the source code, it has a class called `Blowfish` that is probably relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure for 5.2, but for 5.3.7+ theres a simple file you can include to add this PHP5.5 functionality.

There is a compatibility pack available for PHP versions 5.3.7 and later, so you don't have to wait on version 5.5 for using this function. It comes in form of a single php file:
https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

- by martinstoeckli - 
  http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php